# office.js refresh pivot table in excel workbook is not working

Tags: office-js

We are building an excel addin which deals with a pivot table. We want to refresh the pivot table from the data source. We want to implement the same functionality of the `Refresh All Connections` button on `Data` tab. But we want to do it from code using office.js.

We tried the following code snippet. It did not work.

```js
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var pivotTables = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().pivotTables;//.load("items");
    pivotTables.refreshAll();
    return ctx.sync().then(function () {
        //var table = pivotTables.items[0];
        //table.refresh();
        //pivotTables.refreshAll();
    }).then(ctx.sync);
});
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're code isn't wrong, but your expectations for what `refreshAll` is doing here is a bit off. This method will refresh the pivot table to reflect any changes made to the data backing it. This is not the same thing as pulling a fresh snapshot of the data itself.

An example for using this method would be if your add-in made several changes to a matrix of data, once this was complete you would execute a `refreshAll()` to have your data changes reflected in the Pivot Table.

It currently isn't possible to trigger a refresh of a data connection using office.js.

Comment: thanks @marc-lafleur-msft
It is not clear to me what you mean by the backing data. Is not the database the backing store for the pivot table? you mentioned the "matrix of data". What does it refer?

Comment: Your Pivot Table is actually connected to data within your Workbook (typically on another worksheet). This data might have been pulled from a DB but it is still just a snapshot of the data. Refreshing a Pivot Table syncs your Pivot with your Worksheet. Refreshing your Data pulls a new snapshot from the DB. It is refreshing your data that is not supported via JS.